# Cannot access alphabetic host with curl_multi

Tags: php, laravel, curl, request

I have really strange problem with curl working on Laravel 5.5 and php7.
When i use just single connection i don't have any problem with this curl function:

```
    function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    }
```

I'm trying to access local php file with information, multiple times at the same time. I'm using VHOST with the apache: server.local and the file is in that folder server.local/request.php. So with this curl function above it's working as i'm expecting.

The problem is when i have to use it in another function to get multiple requests at the same time with curl_multi and here is the code:

```
    foreach($data as $key => $fetch) {  
        $info[$key]['name'] = $fetch->name;
        $info[$key]['url'] = 'http://server.local/request.php?url='.$fetch->url;
    }

$multi = curl_multi_init();
$channels = array();

foreach ($info as $url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false );
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 2 );
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //timeout in seconds

    curl_multi_add_handle($multi, $ch);

    $channels[$url['url']] = $ch;
}

$active = null;
do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($multi, $active);
} while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($multi) == -1) {
        continue;
    }
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($multi, $active);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}

$i = 0;
dd($channels);
foreach ($channels as $channel) {
    $info[$i]['data'] = curl_multi_getcontent($channel);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($multi, $channel);
    $i++;
}

curl_multi_close($multi);
```

So i tried every combination in the curl_setopt with the commented and uncommented lines. Nothing worked! The only way it works is when i put the request.php in the main web directory and changed server.local with 127.0.0.1. I tried even to apply working real website, and still didn't get anything.

The code i receive in dd($channels); is this:

```
array:1 [▼
  "http://server.local/request.php" => curl resource @276 ▼
    url: "http://server.local/request.php"
    content_type: null
    http_code: 0
    header_size: 0
    request_size: 0
    filetime: -1
    ssl_verify_result: 0
    redirect_count: 0
    total_time: 0.0
    namelookup_time: 0.0
    connect_time: 0.0
    pretransfer_time: 0.0
    size_upload: 0.0
    size_download: 0.0
    speed_download: 0.0
    speed_upload: 0.0
    download_content_length: -1.0
    upload_content_length: -1.0
    starttransfer_time: 0.0
    redirect_time: 0.0
    redirect_url: ""
    primary_ip: ""
    certinfo: []
    primary_port: 0
    local_ip: ""
    local_port: 0
  }
]
```

And just for the protocol, in request.php i have only one Hello World... The request is returning "Hello World" in the browser load, and even in Terminal curl request. I don't know what i've could done wrong? Please help :/

Comment: Consider using [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) which does use `cURL` if available but saves you from the nuances of doing a multi-exec.

Comment: I read about it, but i prefer curl, i think i have more control with it.

Comment: Fair point, but you have even more control writing CGI programs in C (where cURL is also a native library) instead of in PHP but at some point we all sacrifice low level control for quick development and less error-prone code.

Comment: That's beyond my ability :/

Comment: apokryfos was simply making a point that we sacrifice control for ease of implementation. He is not saying that you should write your implementation in C.